# TypeScript generics: Props with union type in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the code below, I get an error on the line `props.onChange(e.target.value as typeof props.value)`: "Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & string[]'."

`e.target.value` is of type `unknown`. If `onChange` was only of type `(value: string) => void`, then I would just cast like so: `props.onChange(e.target.value as string)` and that would work. Likewise for `string[]`.

There's probably a way to make this work with generics, right? I have not figured out how.

(I include the type of `e` for clarity; it is not necessary to make that explicit).

```js
import { MenuItem, Select } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { ChangeEvent, FC } from 'react';

interface SingleProps {
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
  multiple: false;
}

interface MultiProps {
  value: string[];
  onChange: (value: string[]) => void;
  multiple: true;
}

const ReportDateSelect: FC<SingleProps | MultiProps> = props => (
  <Select
    value={props.value}
    onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<{ name?: string; value: unknown }>) =>
      props.onChange(e.target.value as typeof props.value)
    }
    multiple={props.multiple}
  >
    {[1, 2, 3].map((c, i) => (
      <MenuItem key={i} value={c}>
        {c}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
);

export default ReportDateSelect;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues is that when you run `props.onChange`, typescript doesn't actually know which one it's running.

With how you have it set up, you can get the typescript errors fixed by changing the `onChange` function to:

```
    onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<{ name?: string; value: typeof props.value }>) =>{
      if(props.multiple){
        props.onChange(e.target.value as typeof props.value)
      }else{
        props.onChange(e.target.value as typeof props.value)
      }
    }}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgWQKYDsCuBJGqQA0cAyqgDaoDG8AvnAGZQQhwDkAAiAIZ5TBdkAtJmAB6StFSsA3AChQkWHABKqLtSJIAwgAsu6AOaoAogDcMMIgDEtcOo2Zsoa6jNnz0veutQlghigAFJjAAZ0RZODhTAUxUAC44UJg%20QzkoiHRdfSNEgAoYsjjE5NSDAEo4AF4APmiIYAATdLgQTDIYYDAKRO8yUNQ5Gnd-Lx8Uds7giDCIqMLipJT-AwBtAF0WzOzDBLgC2L3SlY3K2vqmlraOrp64FLih9wl0ZJVURRgAER5UUgpqIkbAAeYgrIIhcIAHwmN2mYTqVTgYEh1TqeUicFB5CoMEx80OVQQKJmoQAdAtUMMohksnpdkS8nsdkYzBZgUh0FwQKgAPwlZZpaKHRIwACeYFQEHoyMhFMOdhqZxqCHxNOA9DyJLCZOunW6qHKqppJtlpLJ23pRiZZJgXCgRhg8qKvi44XFkulZp1lPKaqiNHIA2Npqi2vJlpyqBtdodqCdlLgbvuEqlMvDzriftD1JpNFzUT1t1QRIzRYNuZqaoQqwAjEQAExEADM611XDAeTylCIwGV%2039WLQWFw%20DgAGtUGKicA6JSiZQaFXQ1EEIvB8DRMOcHgQMuaeVyrnN-9cVXynJZKgAB6fOCNVDeSbvT4-PCn6hyIA)

Here is one way to do a generic approach. For this, I wasn't sure how to make the multiple prop require true if the Type was an array, so I just made that happen in the actual component using `Array#isArray`

```
interface ReportDateSelectProps<Type = string | string[]> {
  value: Type;
  onChange: (value: Type) => void;
}

function ReportDateSelect<Type = string | string[]>(props: ReportDateSelectProps<Type>): React.ReactNode {
  return (
    <Select
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<{ name?: string; value: Type }>) =>
        props.onChange(e.target.value)
      }
      multiple={Array.isArray(props.value)}
    >
      {[1, 2, 3].map((c, i) => (
        <MenuItem key={i} value={c}>
          {c}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}
export default ReportDateSelect;
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgWQKYDsCuBJGqQA0cAyqgDaoDG8AvnAGZQQhwDkAAiAIZ5TBdkAtJmAB6StFSsA3AChQkWHABKqLtSJIAwgAsu6AOaoAogDcMMOo2Zsoa6jNnz0veutQrUimABEeqUgpqAAUmMABnAB4AFQBPMA8AXjhwmD5DOAAfFLTgQwBtAF0APkRZODhTAUxUAC44OIS5Coh0XX0jeoAKKrIa%20sbUAEo4RNLTCGAAEzkaJ3pMdGpgVs9vPzxAqhgY%20KSc9IMsg7yDIuKusDDw%20tV1-y2Q692E4qHb%20xgAOlV1GAA5CBTDwIcpwOwwTBQdBwLpgiqRR4weEVSrVVCJBBXCARL69GpzVGo1rtQwYhBdOpwUlGMwWSJIdBcECoAD89VSh2kaL6VMGcBob1GxRRROxuJJejJlK%20MC4UCM33xw1FAtVIEwZBgwDAFExAEEoFAuLEvsBwobjbFLtc8eihoTUSKiRUEPkAIxEABMRAAzIUvtwwF0upQiMARmNYaqEWgsLh8HAANaoWKY4B0ZWYyiCmOohA5vORURxnB4EDOl1DB0o4tIytDWayVAAD28cGBbk18Du0F8D3I2zkQA)